# StreamWriter C# formatting output

Tags: c#, streamwriter

**Problem Statement**

In order to run gene annotation software, I need to prepare two types of files, vcard files and coverage tables, and there has to be one-to-one match of vcard to coverage table. Since Im running 2k samples, its hard to identify which file is not one-to-one match. I know that both files have unique identifier numbers, hence, if both folders have files that have same unique numbers, i treat that as "same" file

---

I made a program that compares two folders and reports unique entries in each folder. To do so, I made two list that contains unique file names to each directory.

I want to format the report file (tab delimited .txt file) such that it looks something like below:

```
Unique in fdr1    Unique in fdr2
file x    file a
file y    file b
file z    file c
```

I find this difficult to do because I have to iterate twice (since I have two lists), but there is no way of going back to the previous line in StreamWriter as far as I know. Basically, once I iterate through the first list and fill the first column, how can I fill the second column with the second list?

Can someone help me out with this?

Thanks

If design of the code has to change (i.e. one list instead of two), please let me know

As requested by some user, this is how I was going to do (not working version)

```
// Write report
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(dest_txt.Text + @"\" + "Report.txt"))
        {
            // Write headers
            sw.WriteLine("Unique Entries in Folder1" + "\t" + "Unique Entries in Folder2");

            // Write unique entries in fdr1
            foreach(string file in fdr1FileList)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(file + "\t");
            }

            // Write unique entries in fdr2
            foreach (string file in fdr2FileList)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(file + "\t");
            }
            sw.Dispose();
        }
```

As requested for my approach for finding unique entries, here's my code snippet

```
        Dictionary<int, bool> fdr1Dict = new Dictionary<int, bool>();
        Dictionary<int, bool> fdr2Dict = new Dictionary<int, bool>();

        List<string> fdr1FileList = new List<string>();
        List<string> fdr2FileList = new List<string>();

        string fdr1Path = folder1_txt.Text;
        string fdr2Path = folder2_txt.Text;

        // File names in the specified directory; path not included
        string[] fdr1FileNames = Directory.GetFiles(fdr1Path).Select(Path.GetFileName).ToArray();
        string[] fdr2FileNames = Directory.GetFiles(fdr2Path).Select(Path.GetFileName).ToArray();

        // Iterate through the first directory, and add GL number to dictionary
        for(int i = 0; i < fdr1FileNames.Length; i++)
        {
            // Grabs only the number from the file name
            string number = Regex.Match(fdr1FileNames[i], @"\d+").ToString();
            int glNumber;

            // Make sure it is a number
            if(Int32.TryParse(number, out glNumber))
            {
                fdr1Dict[glNumber] = true;
            }
            // If number not present, raise exception
            else
            {
                throw new Exception(String.Format("GL Number not found in: {0}", fdr1FileNames[i]));
            }

        }

        // Iterate through the second directory, and add GL number to dictionary
        for (int i = 0; i < fdr2FileNames.Length; i++)
        {
            // Grabs only the number from the file name
            string number = Regex.Match(fdr2FileNames[i], @"\d+").ToString();
            int glNumber;

            // Make sure it is a number
            if (Int32.TryParse(number, out glNumber))
            {
                fdr2Dict[glNumber] = true;
            }
            // If number not present, raise exception
            else
            {
                throw new Exception(String.Format("GL Number not found in: {0}", fdr2FileNames[i]));
            }
        }

       // Iterate through the first directory, and find files that are unique to it
        for (int i = 0; i < fdr1FileNames.Length; i++)
        {
            int glNumber = Int32.Parse(Regex.Match(fdr1FileNames[i], @"\d+").Value);
            // If same file is not present in the second folder add to the list
            if(!fdr2Dict[glNumber])
            {
                fdr1FileList.Add(fdr1FileNames[i]);
            }
        }

        // Iterate through the second directory, and find files that are unique to it
        for (int i = 0; i < fdr2FileNames.Length; i++)
        {
            int glNumber = Int32.Parse(Regex.Match(fdr2FileNames[i], @"\d+").Value);
            // If same file is not present in the first folder add to the list
            if (!fdr1Dict[glNumber])
            {
                fdr2FileList.Add(fdr2FileNames[i]);
            }
```

Comment: Can you post your code of what you've tried so far, so we can help you identify the issue?

Comment: What do you mean by UNIQUE entry? Each file in a dir has a different name. Do you mean for example 2 files like `name.test` and `name.test2`?

Comment: To specify problem statement, in order to run gene annotation software, I need to prepare two types of files, vcard files and coverage tables, and there has to be one-to-one match of vcard to coverage table. Since Im running 2k samples, its hard to identify which file is not one-to-one match. I know that both files have unique identifier numbers, hence, if both folders have files that have same unique numbers, i treat that as "same" file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a quite confident that this will work as I've tested it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var firstDir = @"Path1";
    var secondDir = @"Path2";

    var firstDirFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(firstDir);
    var secondDirFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(secondDir);
    print2Dirs(firstDirFiles, secondDirFiles);

}

private static void print2Dirs(string[] firstDirFile, string[] secondDirFiles)
{
    var maxIndex = Math.Max(firstDirFile.Length, secondDirFiles.Length);

    using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter("result.txt"))
    {
        streamWriter.WriteLine(string.Format("{0,-150}{1,-150}", "Unique in fdr1", "Unique in fdr2"));
        for (int i = 0; i < maxIndex; i++)
        {
            streamWriter.WriteLine(string.Format("{0,-150}{1,-150}",
                firstDirFile.Length > i ? firstDirFile[i] : string.Empty,
                secondDirFiles.Length > i ? secondDirFiles[i] : string.Empty));
        }
    }
}
```

It's a quite simple code but if you need help understanding it just let me know :)

Comment: Wouldn't it raise exception if two folders have different number of files? i.e. if list1.Count == 50, and list2.Count == 30, would it still work? Oh nevermind

Comment: No it will not as i've implemented a very ugly method to check it. Of course you can do it in a better way, but i will not raise any exception. I've tested with one dir with 1 file and other with 3

Comment: Thanks, It worked. If you happen to find more elegant solution, please update the post

Comment: @djskj189 how exactly is this answer valid if it doesnt manage the unique numeric entries of the files? ._.

Comment: @Innat3 he has different file names

Comment: @Sid he said he has two directories and he wants to output the filenames which have an unique numeric keyword which is not existent in both directories. Your exact same "answer" was already posted earlier and discarded by the OP as incomplete, and now the OP suddenly chose to accept your answer? this is absolute bullshit if you ask me

Comment: @Innat3 well I understand that you took your time to write your answer as I did, but avoid such language here.

Comment: @Innat3  I know steve's answer is very similar to Sid answer, but earlier answer did not work properly.. Besides my original question (and still is) was about formatting the output, not finding unique entries (I already knew how to do that). I just selected the first answer that actually worked. Sincerely sorry if this offended you

Answer (score 0):

I would construct each line at a time. Something like this:

```
int row = 0;
string[] fdr1FileList = new string[0];
string[] fdr2FileList = new string[0];

while (row < fdr1FileList.Length || row < fdr2FileList.Length)
{
    string rowText = "";
    rowText += (row >= fdr1FileList.Length ? "\t" : fdr1FileList[row] + "\t");
    rowText += (row >= fdr2FileList.Length ? "\t" : fdr2FileList[row]);
    row++;
}
```

Comment: This is likeyly to cause and `IndexOutOfBoundException`

Comment: It won't because it checks before accessing the array if the index is within bounds (the row >= fdr1FileList.Length bit)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<int, string> fdr1Dict = FilesToDictionary(Directory.GetFiles("path1"));
        Dictionary<int, string> fdr2Dict = FilesToDictionary(Directory.GetFiles("path2"));

        var unique_f1 = fdr1Dict.Where(f1 => !fdr2Dict.ContainsKey(f1.Key)).ToArray();
        var unique_f2 = fdr2Dict.Where(f2 => !fdr1Dict.ContainsKey(f2.Key)).ToArray();

        int f1_size = unique_f1.Length;
        int f2_size = unique_f2.Length;
        int list_length = 0;

        if (f1_size > f2_size)
        {
            list_length = f1_size;
            Array.Resize(ref unique_f2, list_length);
        }
        else
        {
            list_length = f2_size;
            Array.Resize(ref unique_f1, list_length);
        }


        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("output.txt"))
        {
            writer.WriteLine(string.Format("{0,-30}{1,-30}", "Unique in fdr1", "Unique in fdr2"));
            for (int i = 0; i < list_length; i++)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(string.Format("{0,-30}{1,-30}", unique_f1[i].Value, unique_f2[i].Value));
            }
        }
    }
    static Dictionary<int, string> FilesToDictionary(string[] filenames)
    {
        Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < filenames.Length; i++)
        {
            int glNumber;
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(filenames[i]);
            string number = Regex.Match(filename, @"\d+").ToString();

            if (int.TryParse(number, out glNumber))
                dict.Add(glNumber, filename);
        }
        return dict;
    }
```

Comment: f1.Except won't work in my case because files actually have different names. They just have same identifier numbers. I didn't know this would cause confusion, sorry.

Comment: @djskj189 so how did you plan to get the unique filenames? can you provide samples of the file name structure?

Comment: I used Regex to strip out the number from file name. Ill edit the post to include "Detect Unique File name" algorithm